# access the .push key of firebase database for updating Profile info in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push

I am developing an android app with `Firebase`, so saving data to Firebase with .`push` method and displaying them into `list` , i want to update the `UserInfo` stored in database but confused how i can access `push` method generated `Key` to update profile info , or any other way to setting profile info under the Authenticated user ID and read all this data so it will update on the list i am displaying.
[image]

or any other method to access this by `User_id` in child values?

myOnBtnClick code below

```
btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (Validation()) {
                final String name = Field_fullName.getText().toString();
                String phone = firebaseUser.getPhoneNumber();
                String bg = field_bloodGroups.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String DOB = Field_dateOfBirth.getText().toString();
                String state = Field_state.getText().toString();
                final String country = Field_country.getText().toString();
                String city = Field_city.getText().toString();
                UserSignUp userSignUp = new UserSignUp(name, phone, bg, DOB, state, country, city, firebaseUser.getUid());
                DBref.child("DONORS").child(country).push().setValue(userSignUp).addOnCompleteListener(reg.this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(reg.this, DBref.getKey() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(reg.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            editor = sharedPreference.edit();
                            editor.putInt("UserReg", 1);
                            editor.putString("UserCountry", country);
                            editor.putInt("FirstTimeRun", 1);
                            editor.apply();
                            startActivity(new Intent(reg.this, Main2Activity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the `push()` method to generate that unique key, is the moment in which you can get and store the key like this:

```
String key = yourRef.getKey();
```

And to update a record please use the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Pakistan")
    .child(key)
    .child("user_ID")
    .setValue("123456789");
```

**Edit:**

```
DatabaseReference keyRef = DBref.child("DONORS").child(country).push();
String key = keyRef.getKey();
Log("TAG", key);
keyRef.setValue(userSignUp).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

Once you have this key, you can use it in other DatabaseReference. When you are using `DBref.getKey()` inside `onComplete()` method isn't getting the pushed key is just getting the key of your `DBref`.

Comment: nope i tried , by adding into data i am wiriting and also by toasting both tie it differs from generated key. timestamp :(

Comment: This means that you are using the `push()` method twice. Only once is needed. Share us some code.

Comment: i added please check :)

Comment: i check toast to get Key , but it is null

Comment: can you further explain please, keyRef refrence have to use to write data or when need to update data ?

Comment: When you need to write data. When you need to update data, you need to use the **`key`** (not the keyRef), inside a `DatabaseReference` to get to desired location from your tree.

Comment: Ok. Keep me posted.